# Unmarshalling XML with Java Generics (collections)

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I need to unmarshal a piece of XML that I get through Yahoo's YQL Webservices.
The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="8" yahoo:created="2012-07-16T16:43:15Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<results>
    <results>
    <GsearchResultClass>GwebSearch</GsearchResultClass>
    <unescapedUrl>http://www.test.com/nl/nieuws</unescapedUrl>
    <url>http://www.test.com/nl/nieuws</url>
    <visibleUrl>www.test.com</visibleUrl>
    <cacheUrl>http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:0B4z0dyd94gJ:www.test.com</cacheUrl>
    <title>Nieuws | test.com</title>
    <titleNoFormatting>Nieuws | test.com</titleNoFormatting>
    <content>text text text text text text text text  &lt;b&gt;...&lt;/b&gt;</content>
    </results>
    [...]
</results>
</query>
```

The duplicate "results" key is not an error by the way.

I'm trying to unmarshal this with the following classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="query")
public class YQL<T> {

    List<T> results;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="results")
    @XmlElement(name="results")
    public List<T> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<T> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }   
}

@XmlType
public class SearchResult{

    String url,title,content;

    @XmlElement
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
[...]


public class YQLFeedReaderImpl<T> implements FeedReader<YQL<T>> {

private Class<T> resultClazz;

[...]

final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(YQL.class,resultClazz);

final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

URL url = new URL([....]);

return (YQL<T>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(url);
```

What I'm getting returned for T elements are generic ElementNSImpl in stead of SearchResult.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Cheers,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

I ended up refactoring the code to make YQL an interface YQL in stead of a class and creating a class GoogleYQL that implements that interface and treating the entire GoogleYQL class as T. That worked. Still curious if the problem above is resolvable though.